# Wolfram|Alpha API Python NameError: name 'pod' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, wolframalpha

I'm new to the Wolfram|Alpha API for python and I could not find much help on the internet, so I turned to stack overflow. I receive the "NameError: name 'pod' is not defined" on SOME queries on Wolfram|Alpha. Any help would be much appreciated. When I input my query "Length of a Ferrari 458" I used to end up with the StopIteration error, now I've change the code to use "pods" method. Now I get a NameError. The out put should give me the length of the car (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=length+of+ferrari+458) I had to x out app_id as it's not mine, sorry for the inconvenience.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import wolframalpha
app_id=('xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx')
client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)

query = input("Query:")
if len(res.pods) > 0:
texts = ""
pod = res.pods[1]

if pod.text:
  texts = pod.text

else:
  texts = "I have no answer for that"

texts = texts.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
print (texts)
```

The error I get:

```
 Query: length of ferrari 458
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "Wolfram.py", line 24, in <module>
       if pod.text:
  NameError: name 'pod' is not defined
```

Comment: The `res.results` generator is empty. I'm not familiar with the API, perhaps `res.pods` shares the same generator?

Comment: Please update your question to add what output you *expected* instead.

Comment: The [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wolframalpha) suggests you need to use *one* or the *other*, not both techniques.

Comment: I've used a different method - using pods. ALOT more efficient than before on answering questions, Unfortunately cannot still answer some of them.

Answer (score 0):

If a sequence is empty [**`next`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) raises an exception.

Pass `None` as a second parameter to return as a default. From the linked [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

> `next(iterator[, default])`
>   Retrieve the next item from the *iterator* by calling its `next()` method. If *default* is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted, otherwise `StopIteration` is raised.

If there are no results and you don't want to handle the exception:

```
first = next(res.results, None)
if first:
    print(first.text)
```

If there are no results, `first` will be `None`, which you can then check before trying to use it.

Comment: Yup, `next()` can return a default, but that won't help solve the issue that there is no results however. And then you'll get an attribute error on `.text`.

Comment: The question is posed as a `StopIteration` problem rather than an empty `results` attribute problem.

Comment: I would like to be able to query without any error occurring obviously. For example my input: "Top speed for Ferrari 458" and I want it to return with out StopIteration. As I'm new I don't quite understand by pass none as a second parameter to return as a default.

Comment: @PeterWood: no, it is a *this doesn't work, I get a `StopIteration` exception. There is no *I expected these results* part to determine one way or another what the OP actually wants to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use the generator twice, without making the query twice, you could use `itertools.tee` to have two copies of the generator for you to use:

```
from itertools import tee

res1, res2 = tee(res, 2)

# consume the first generator:
for pod in res1:
    ...
    ...

# you have a second generator you can use:
print(next(res2.results).text)
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The [source code](https://github.com/jaraco/wolframalpha/blob/master/wolframalpha/__init__.py) shows that `res.pods` and `res.results` share the same iterator. The error you are getting simply means there are *no results*. Try a different query.

The sample query works, for example:

```
>>> res = client.query('temperature in Washington, DC on October 3, 2012')
>>> print(next(res.results).text)
(21 to 27) °C (average: 24 °C)
(Wednesday, October 3, 2012)
>>> [p.title for p in res]
['Input interpretation', 'Result', 'History', 'Weather station information']
```

Your specific query doesn't return any results, apparently because there are assumptions to confirm; visiting `http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input=length+of+a+Ferrari+458&appid=<your-app-id>` produces:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<queryresult success='false'
    error='false'
    numpods='0'
    datatypes=''
    timedout=''
    timedoutpods=''
    timing='2.742'
    parsetiming='0.79'
    parsetimedout='false'
    recalculate=''
    id='MSPa12051ddfeh1dgh883d2e000035eh08fba72b042e'
    host='http://www4f.wolframalpha.com'
    server='9'
    related=''
    version='2.6'
    profile='EnterDoQuery:0.,StartWrap:2.74235'>
 <didyoumeans count='2'>
  <didyoumean score='0.365929' level='medium'>Ferrari 458</didyoumean>
  <didyoumean score='0.26087' level='low'>length</didyoumean>
 </didyoumeans>
</queryresult>
```

How you can get from there to the `2015 Ferrari 458 Italia | overall length` query that the web interface manages to extract is not clear from the API documentation.

You *can* access the `didyoumean` elements via the `Result.tree` attribute, using the [`ElementTree` API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
>>> res = client.query('length of a Ferrari 458')
>>> for didyoumean in res.tree.findall('//didyoumean'):
...     print didyoumean.text
...
Ferrari 458
length
```

Comment: Thanks Martijin, useful but still doesn't give me an answer to my query. Is there no possible way for it to be answered using the Wolfram API?

Comment: I have not found a way. The API documentation doesn't give any hints either.